# Post back is not working for dynamically added items dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding drop down list dynamically I am successful in that but event is not fired when drop down list selected index changed. It is fired when the pre existing add button in the page. Here is my code:

design page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="textboxespanel" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Сode-behind:

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
    controlidlist = (List<string>)ViewState["controlidlist"];
    foreach (string Id in controlidlist)
    {
        i++;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = Id;
        LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl();
        DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
        dl.ID = "dropdownlist" + i;
        dl.DataTextField = "cloth";
        dl.DataValueField = "cloth";
        dl.DataSource = obj.getclothitems();

        dl.DataBind();
        DropDownList dldl = new DropDownList();
        dldl.ID = "dropdownlistdropdownlist" + i;
        dldl.Items.Insert(0, "MALE");
        dldl.Items.Insert(0, "FEMALE");
        dldl.Items.Insert(0, "HOME");

        dldl.SelectedIndexChanged += dropdownlistchanged1;
        dldl.AutoPostBack = true;
        //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
        //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);

        textboxespanel.Controls.Add(tb);
        textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        textboxespanel.Controls.Add(dldl);
        textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        textboxespanel.Controls.Add(dl);
        textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "textboxes" + i;
    tb.Text = "textbox" + i;
    DropDownList dldl = new DropDownList();
    dldl.ID = "dropdownlistdropdownlist" + i;
    dldl.Items.Insert(0, "MALE");
    dldl.Items.Insert(0, "FEMALE");
    dldl.Items.Insert(0, "HOME");

    dldl.SelectedIndexChanged += dropdownlistchanged1;
    dldl.AutoPostBack = true;

    DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
    dl.ID = "dropdownlist" + i;
    dl.DataTextField = "cloth";
    dl.DataValueField = "cloth";
    dl.DataSource = obj.getclothitems();

    dl.DataBind();

    LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl("<br>");
    //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
    //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(tb);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(dldl);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(dl);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    controlidlist.Add(tb.ID);
    ViewState["controlidlist"] = controlidlist;
}

public void dropdownlistchanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList lbtn = (DropDownList)sender;
    string id = lbtn.ID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add controls in Init Event, more information on [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e){
base.OnInit(e);
controlidlist = ViewState["controlidlist"] as List<string>;
if(controlidlist !=null)
{
foreach (string Id in controlidlist)
{
    i++;
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = Id;
    LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl();
    DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
    dl.ID = "dropdownlist" + i;
    dl.DataTextField = "cloth";
    dl.DataValueField = "cloth";
    dl.DataSource = obj.getclothitems();

    dl.DataBind();
    DropDownList dldl = new DropDownList();
    dldl.ID = "dropdownlistdropdownlist" + i;
    dldl.Items.Insert(0, "MALE");
    dldl.Items.Insert(0, "FEMALE");
    dldl.Items.Insert(0, "HOME");

    dldl.SelectedIndexChanged += dropdownlistchanged1;
    dldl.AutoPostBack = true;
    //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
    //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);

    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(tb);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(dldl);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(dl);
    textboxespanel.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
}
}
}
```

Comment: How to do that can you please elaborate. Thank You

Comment: it is not working i am able to add only one item at a time that too postback is not working

Answer (score 1):

Its worked after placing the total panel in the update panel.

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>


    <asp:Panel ID="textboxespanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="bbb" runat="server" Text="cc" OnClick="bbb_Click" />

    </asp:Panel>
 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```